# How can I disable Street Fighter IV from lowering my volume during multiplayer battles?

Tags: steam, super-street-fighter-iv

When I play Street Fighter IV AE in Steam and I open or join a multiplayer game the volume of my music (e.g. iTunes, Spotify) gets lowered.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

This is windows reacting to a "telephone call" because someone has a microphone plugged in.

You can disable this "feature" like this:

- Open Start -> Control Panel -> Sound
- Switch to the Communications Panel
- Select "Do nothing"

This will disable this feature for every application including Steam.

[image]